# Where should the water holes be in an outdoor plant pot?

Tags: watering, containers, outdoor

I have some balcony plant pots like these:
[image: "geli Standard Kunststoff Blumenkasten"]

They have no holes at the bottom, so I'm planning to drill holes to prevent water from accumulating at the bottom and causing rot.

But as you can see there are these "nubs" at the bottom; and now I'm wondering: should I drill the holes at the top of the nubs, so that water from the lowest 2 cm of the pot cannot flow out; or should I drill the holes really in the bottom plate so that all water can eventually drain?

In case it matters: I'm planning to put the pots on a "pan" so that the water does not drop down to the neighbors. Also, I have LECA (swelling clay?) available to put into the bottom of the pot.

The pots are supposed be used for tomatoes, strawberries, and spices (like rosemary, sage, thyme, oregano). Some will be placed under a roof, others will occasionally get natural rain.

Comment: Why not do both? Both at the top of the nubs and in the bottom? I have such containers as well, but with mines there is an indication where to drill (round sign with drill drawn next to it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignore the raised bits and drill the holes in the base- usually, there are round 'impressions' or thinner bits of plastic  where  the holes are meant to go, but if not, put about 4 small holes in each end with another 4 in the middle, between the two raised nubs.